# Why does this query have only one result?

Tags: mysql

This query should be repeated over all table tags data:

```
SELECT tags.*, COUNT(users.tags) AS followers 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN users ON users.tags LIKE CONCAT("%,",tags.id,",%") 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY followers DESC
```

When I run this command it only shows one result, despite the fact that there are more than 20 rows. This is true even if I have `WHERE 1` in the query.

I saw that if I replace the `COUNT(users.tags)` with `users.tags` it shows more than one result, but does not include the count.

I'm just try to get data from tags and count users that have the id of the tag in their tags column.

Comment: Note that `WHERE 1` does not modify the results, because `1` will always evaluate to `true`. You should simply drop that clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT()` is an [**aggregate function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html). So, it will automatically group all of the rows, unless you have a `GROUP BY` clause. Try something like this:

```
SELECT tags.*, COUNT(users.tags) AS followers
FROM tags
    INNER JOIN users ON users.tags LIKE CONCAT("%,",tags.id,",%")
WHERE 1
GROUP BY tags.id -- NOTE: you may need to specify a different field here; not sure what you want
ORDER BY followers DESC
```

Comment: do you know how can i also show result of tags that their followers counted 0?

Comment: That's going to be a very different query, but you probably want `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. [See this graphical explanation of join types](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).